# How to set 'Country' field of TimeZone when using Google Calendar API?

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

When I created calendar with Google Calendar API (Python), I'm setting timezone to by adding it to the request message:

```
    calendar = {
        'summary': 'My Title',
        'description': 'My Description',
        'timeZone': 'China/Shanghai'
    }
    gService = build('calendar', 'v3', http=self.http, developerKey='XXXXXXXX')
    gService.calendars().insert(body=calendar).execute()
```

The created calendar got correct timezone. This part is good. But when I view the calendar setting at http://calendar.google.com, the Country field in TimeZone configuration is always 'United States', even the selected timezone is 'China Time - BeiJing'.

Is there any way to correct this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should add one line between

```
 'description': 'My Description',
 'timeZone': 'China/Shanghai'
```

That says

```
'location': 'China',
```

I am basing this off the general [API v3 documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars).

Comment: That seems not correct. Location field doesn't affect TimeZone - Country field at all. Actually, you can put any text to this field and Google doesn't parse it at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It might be that google doesn't support that / notation for Chinese cities because there is only one time zone in china. They also don't have day light savings, so you don't have to worry about that.

I would try setting

```
'timeZone': 'China/Shanghai'
```

to

```
"timeZone" : "China Standard Time"
```

I am basing this on the output from google timezone API (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/) with the coordinates of Shanghai:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/timezone/json?location=31.224546,121.401215&timestamp=1331161200&sensor=false

which gives the output:

```
{
   "dstOffset" : 0,
   "rawOffset" : 28800,
   "status" : "OK",
   "timeZoneId" : "Asia/Chongqing",
   "timeZoneName" : "China Standard Time"
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It can be easily tested at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert